# Random favicon at every refresh

Tags: php, favicon

I am trying to make a script which changes the favicon at every refresh.

```
<?php
 $dir = "img/icons/";
 $files = array();
 if ($handle = opendir($dir)) {
   while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
    $files[] = $file;
   }
 }
 $icon = $files[rand(2,count($files)-1)];
 echo "<LINK REL=\"shortcut icon\" HREF=\'img/icons/'.$icon."\">";
?>
```

This script gets every favicon from the /img/icons folder, and randomly selects one. The problem is that when I paste it in my HTML file, weird characters appear at the top of the page "; ?>.Can anyone fix my script ?

Comment: You are not escaping some of the quotations properly.

Comment: If you've not changed your server settings you can't run php in a html file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
 $dir = "img/icons/";
 $files = array();
 if ($handle = opendir($dir)) {
   while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
    $files[] = $file;
   }
 }
 $icon = $files[rand(2,count($files)-1)];
 echo '<LINK REL="shortcut icon" HREF="img/icons/'.$icon.'">';
?>
```

**[Here](http://www.ntchosting.com/php/php-in-html.html)** you can have a look at using PHP in HTML. Also your server should be properly configured for this. I always recommend `.php` to deal with PHP scripts.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
echo "<LINK REL=\"shortcut icon\" HREF='img/icons/$icon'>";
```

Not tested.

You didn't do your escaping correctly.

---

**EDIT:** I would use a modified version Evan Mulawski's solution. I think the unmodified version is a lot easier to read.

My modifications would be:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/icons/<?php echo "$icon" ?>"/>
```

I do this because on a few systems php on nginx sometimes becomes a bit slow like ~50ms I have read it somewhere on the web.

Answer (score 1):

As my comment stated, you are not escaping some of the quotations properly. Single quotes are not escaped when inside double quotes (an vice-versa).

Replace your `echo` line with:

```
?>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo "img/icons/$icon" ?>"/>
```

Explanation:

You can integrate HTML inside PHP code. Write the `link` tag in plain HTML after closing the PHP tag and just use PHP when you need to echo the icon location. It is much easier than trying to escape quotations.

Comment: When your script gets executed/loaded in the html files, it becomes something like `<!--?php
$dir = "img/icons/";
$files = array();
if ($handle = opendir($dir)) {  
 while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {  
  $files[] = $file;  
 }
}
$icon = $files[rand(2,count($files)-1)]; 
?-->
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="&lt;?php echo " img="" icons="" $icon"="" ?="">
</head>
<body>
""/&gt;
  "`

Comment: @KristoKrisztian Weird. On my system it looks normal just a `<link>` tag with a `href` and a `rel`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Using single quotes for string helps avoid the issue of using escape characters.

```
echo '<LINK REL="shortcut icon" HREF="img/icons/' . $icon . '">';
```